# My first GWT Module

Tags: gwt

I created a module to share code across a couple of projects.

I created a GWT project: Framework. I then created a module com.framework.Framework within the project. The Framework project contains both client code, in the com.framework.client packages, and server code in the com.framework.server packages.

I try to consume this by
 - Adding the project to the Java Build Path
 - Adding  to the module's definition

When I run the consuming project, I get NoClassDefFoundErrors for Framework classes I use in the module's server code.

What am I missing?

If I jar up the Framework project's WEB-INF\classes contents and put it into the consuming project's WEB-INF\lib folder, as well as add it to the Build Path it seems to work, but I don't see a way to keep the framework classes up to date in the consuming project(s).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you create gwt.xml file via menu New->Module, and in this gwt.xml file, you must declare your entry point class.

Comment: Thanks. I used the New->Module menu item and added an entry point. When I run it gets loaded (I see a GWT.log). My issue is that I have RemoteServiceServlet that extends a framework class and get ClassNotFoundErrors when the web app tries to load.

Comment: Please check tutorial here: http://code.google.com/intl/vi/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

Maybe you declared wrong way of RPC service, or missing servlet-mapping

Comment: It set up correctly.

If I jar up the Framework project's WEB-INF\classes contents and put it into the consuming project's WEB-INF\lib folder, as well as add it to the Build Path it seems to work, but I don't see a way to keep the framework classes up to date in the consuming project(s).

Comment: I mean you must declare servlet-mapping and gwt.xml in your consuming project...

For example, in jar file you have com.yoursite.app package, you must create MyApp.gwt.xml at com.yoursite.app **within your consuming project's src/ folder** (not in jar files). And in **web.xml of your consuming project**, you must declare servlet-mapping for your framework jar files (not in jar files too).

**Note:** Please jar up with source code (GWT can not compile your GWT framework with class file, it can only compile source files to JS)